# Find out words with extended letters and just keep first occurence of that letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, text-processing, stop-words

I have a dataframe column that contains text data. It has few words with repetitive letters. I want to find all such words, then store these words as keys in a dictionary and their correct spellings as values in the dictionary and then replace the word in the dataframe with its value in the dictionary.  For example if my dataframe has words like-

```
id   text
1     Hiiiiiii
2     Good morninggggggg
3     See you soooonnnn
```

1) I need to find such words in the dataframe column
2) store these words in dictionary {Hiiiiiii : Hi, morninggggggg : morning, soooonnnn : soon}
3) then replace these words in the dataframe with their values in the dictionary
4) Final output should look like-

```
id   text
1     Hi
2     Good morning
3     See you soon
```

Comment: @coldspeed....is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you know what are the correct spellings? And how do you know that 'hiii' is wrong but 'good' is right?

Comment: @DYZ...so I want to first get all words that have one letter repeated more than 2 times consecutively....there are very few such words in the dataframe I have and when I get a list of such words I will store them in dictionary as keys and their correct spellings as values

Comment: But you did not answer any of my questions. (1) How do you know _not_ to include "good", which has two repeated letter? (2) Where do you get the correct spellings?

Comment: 1) I will first find all words that have one letter repeated more than 2 times consecutively. "good" has "o" repeated just twice so in this case it wont be returned. If it was "goood" it would be returned.
2) Then I will manually make a dictionary with these returned words, for example "goood" and store its value as "good"

Comment: And just if "goood" was the right spelling then it would be returned but i wont include it in dictionary since i know its already in its right form

Answer (score 0):

The following function reports words with repetitions. Bear in mind that `split()` is usually doing a mediocre job on identifying words. You probably want to replace it with `nltk.word_tokenize()`.

```
import re
def find_bad(sent):
    return [w for w in sent.split() 
            if re.search(r'(:?\w)\1\1', w, re.I)]
```

Apply the function to each sentence in the dataframe and collect the results:

```
bad_words = df['text'].apply(find_bad).sum()
# ['Hiiiiiii', 'morninggggggg', 'soooonnnn']
```

I'll skip the dictionary construction part, as it is (a) trivial and (b) requires user interaction. Let's say the dictionary name is `corrections`. Now you can use the dictionary to repair your text:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(corrections, regex=True)
```

Again, bear in mind that `replace` is case-sensitive. You may want to convert all texts to the lower case before any further processing.

Comment: I didnt understand the last part. Can you explain how corrections work?

Comment: The function `replace` replaces the dictionary keys with their values. You may want to read its documentation.

Comment: @DYZ....instead of using a dictionary can we do something like keeping just the first occurrence of the letter and removing all other occurrences?

Comment: You asked for a dictionary, and I provided a solution with a dictionary. Yes, you can do something else, now that you have the fesmework.